# Node red OSC Error "Flows stopped due to missing node types"

Tags: node.js, node-red, osc, opensoundcontrol

I am setting up an OSC receiver at the moment using node-red and node-red-contrib-osc on a Windows 10 machine (Node.js version 12.13.1, npm Version 6.12.1).

Unfortunately, I cannot deploy the flow, node-red throws the following error: "Flows stopped due to missing node types". The OSC plugin was installed using the "Manage pallette" button.

On the console there is the following information logged during installation process:

```
[info] node-red-contrib-osc : Syntax Error : Unexpected token ...
```

When I start Deploy, the following info is logged: [info] Waiting for missing types to be registered: - osc

I can reproduce the issue on two Windows 10 machines and on Raspbian, too.
There are some similar questions here on stackoverflow which I read, but no suggested solution worked for me.

I hope someone has a deeper knowledge than I have.

Answer (score 1):

A syntax error reported against a node can mean either:

- you are using too old a version of Node.js for the code in the module
- there is some other error with the node

Given you are using Node 12, it is unlikely to be the first issue. I suggest you check the node's github issue list to see if there are any known issues in this area and if not, perhaps report what you are seeing there.

https://github.com/njh/node-red-contrib-osc